# DEBUG [org.jboss.naming.Naming] Error writing response to /127.0.0.1 java.net.SocketException

Tags: jboss, intellij-idea

After starting the run/debug configuration begins build and deploy application. All goes well. The only thing that provides continuously JBoss Log SocketException:

[image]

```
2012-07-16 12:43:30,424 DEBUG [org.jboss.naming.Naming] Error writing response to /127.0.0.1 java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92) at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1756) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1257) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1211) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1395) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:333) at org.jnp.server.Main$BootstrapRequestHandler.run(Main.java:516) at org.jboss.util.threadpool.RunnableTaskWrapper.run(RunnableTaskWrapper.java:148) at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(PooledExecutor.java:756) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

At issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-3417 offer a solution:
*If you set server / etc / host with:
IP fqn name
where IP is in «Error writing response to / IP"
Ex:
... "Error writing response to / 10.1.0.1"
10.1.0.1 test.mydomain test
you resolve the problem*

But I have something 127.0.0.1 localhost, it is already registered in the default c:\ Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

In the [Troubleshooting](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:4oei_s0GlncJ:cagrid.org/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=16023560%20%22Error%20writing%20response%20to%20/127.0.0.1%22&hl=kk&gl=kz&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESix9tdr0wSLvt0DpYM08AKbJkMRndOUW-qLM58etwOOxVGghrTkBk5SmbBhFrn9uwc0TApCZsGI5izNpTArhlVnXE1zlvXtR3lFiAXqlfx7ojl1PKEU1i2ixTYr8cz54WVNfHlg&sig=AHIEtbRizF7FbN0qdNxKFIn46O_tdPYeoA) says:
*You may notice something in the JBoss logs similar to the following:*

```
2009-01-28 08:36:57,381 DEBUG
[org.jboss.naming.NamingService]
Error writing response to / 127.0.0.1 <[http://127.0.0.1]>
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0 (Native Method)
```

*This is most likely an anomalous and benign «problem». That is, it should not affect the operation of any applications deployed to JBoss.*

If this does not affect deployed application can be any way to hide it? And then the continuous output overshadows the other posts and eats memory.

Comment: Is there any exception when starting JBoss from command line not IDEA?